# Can I pass List of superclass type to a constructor in where it expects List of its childclass?

Tags: java, inheritance

Late yesterday I ran into this conversation with fellow developers who are very competent but just began to wet their feet into Java.

There is a class `Foo.java` that extends `Bar.java` class.

```
public class Foo extends Bar { .. }
```

One of the developers saw an existing model that consumes `List<Foo>`.

```
List<Foo> fooList = new ArrayList<Foo>();
GoodModel model = new GoodModel(fooList);
```

He thought since Bar is superclass of Foo, he could pass `List<Bar>` to this constructor of the model but compiler didn't like it.

```
List<Bar> barList = new ArrayList<Bar>();
GoodModel model = new GoodModel(barlist); <---- compiler complained
```

He and another developer were trying to understand why and I happened to run into this conversation accidentally but I couldn't help them either. None of us understands inheritance in Java well yet. I bet one of them must have figured it out already why but I decided to ask a question in here that I know seasoned developers are available.

I'd appreciate your reply and advice.

Comment: Think about it. You order a list of 6 shiny new Mac book pros on Amazon (i.e. a List<MacBookPro>). But you get, instead, a list of 6 computers (which might contain 2 mac book pros, but also 2 5-year old chrome books and 2 old asus computers). Would you be happy? No. You asked for a List<MacBookPro>, not for a List<Computer>.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder you had it right from the start: the OP tries to pass a List<SuperClass> to a method expecting a List<SubClass>.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: I wish I could have time to consumer your 1st reply but it is gone.. :-) Thank you for the link you shared. I am digesting it now and will share with others.

Comment: @DaeYoung: It was basically: "No, for at least two reasons: #1 Because generics don't work that way" (e.g., the linked dupetarget) "...and #2, because you can't substitute a `Bar` for a `Foo` anyway (only a `Foo` for a `Bar`)." Happy coding!